# How to pass strings from Listview to Fragments in another class?

Tags: android, string, listview, fragment

I have android project where - ListClass has a Listview. Upon clicking on an item of Listview - opens  CardFlipActivity with two fragments that are set up to be viewed as pageflip action.  I need to play a video on the top fragment and display a image in the bottom fragment of the CardFlipActivity

1) How to pass the strings for the (raw folder video files and image files) from listview item switch position in ListClass to retrieve for display in the fragments of the CardFlipActivity.

**ListClass code:**

```
public class ListClass extends ListActivity {
static final String VIDEO_PATH = null;
static final String IMAGE_PATH = null;
static final String VIDEO_NAME = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into ArrayList
    String[] coronary_pathology_clips = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.coronary_pathology_clips);
    ArrayList<String> coronary_pathology_clipsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(coronary_pathology_clips));

    // Binding resources ArrayList to CathListAdapter
    setListAdapter(new CathListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, coronary_pathology_clipsList));
    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}   
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    change(position);
}
void change(int position){
      String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
      Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CardFlipActivity.class);

    switch(position){  

    case 0 :
        String path1 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;
        String path1a = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.image1;

        intent.putExtra (VIDEO_PATH, path1);  
        intent.putExtra (IMAGE_PATH, path1a);               

        break;
    case 1 :
        String path2 = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video2;
        String path2a = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.image2;

        intent.putExtra (VIDEO_PATH, path2);  
        intent.putExtra (IMAGE_PATH, path2a);   
        break;

    } 
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("VIDEO_NAME", selectedValue);
    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

**CardFlipActivity Code**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CardFlipActivity extends Activity
    implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private boolean mShowingBack = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_flip);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // If there is no saved instance state, add a fragment representing the
        // front of the card to this activity. If there is saved instance state,
        // this fragment will have already been added to the activity.
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
                .commit();
    } else {
        mShowingBack = (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
    }

    // Monitor back stack changes to ensure the action bar shows the appropriate
    // button (either "photo" or "info").
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // Add either a "photo" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
    // is currently selected.
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.action_flip, Menu.NONE,
            mShowingBack
                    ? R.string.action_photo
                    : R.string.action_info);
    item.setIcon(mShowingBack
            ? R.drawable.ic_action_photo
            : R.drawable.ic_action_info);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Navigate "up" the demo structure to the launchpad activity.
            // See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html for more.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, ListClass.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_flip:
            flipCard();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void flipCard() {
    if (mShowingBack) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return;
    }

    // Flip to the back.

    mShowingBack = true;

    // Create and commit a new fragment transaction that adds the fragment for the back of
    // the card, uses custom animations, and is part of the fragment manager's back stack.

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()


            .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

            .replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment())

            .addToBackStack(null)

            .commit();


    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    mShowingBack = (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);

    // When the back stack changes, invalidate the options menu (action bar).
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

/*A fragment representing the frontcard.*/

public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {
    public CardFrontFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_front, container, false);

    }
}

/*A fragment representing the back card.*/

public static class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {
    public CardBackFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container, false);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For passing string to another fragment you can use `setArgument(bundle)` method of fragment.
and to recieve these string you can `getArgument()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use startactivityforresult to get result from listclass.

Comment: Would you please elaborate little more if possible? What code should I write in ListClass and what code should I put in the fragments?

Comment: Have a look at the Android Developer Page here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html